# Can't install Windows Desktop Search 4.0

Tags: windows-search, windows-desktop-search, windows-xp

On a windows XP system, I try to download and install Windows Desktop Search 4.0 and it fails.

The error I get:

```
Windows Search 4.0 could not be installed on this system.

For more details, check the log file.
(C:\Windows\KB940157.log)
```

The contents of that file:
http://pastebin.com/MW37NXCy

No idea how to resolve this. Any help is extremely appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uninstall any previous version of WDS, if you can't uninstall via add/remove programs, run this file:

```
%windir%\$NtUninstallKB917013$\spuninst\spuninst.exe
```

If this doesn't work either, delete the following registry keys:

```
"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Updates\Windows XP\SP3\KB917013"

"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\KB917013"
```

... and try again.

Comment: That uninstaller does not exist, nor do those two registry keys :(

Comment: That KB is for Windows Search V3.01, which I can't install either

Comment: @Ben Baril  - is your windows installer up to date? http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=5a58b56f-60b6-4412-95b9-54d056d6f9f4&displaylang=en

Comment: Installed that, same story still. Any more information I can give you?

Comment: @Ben Baril - i'm running out of ideas, except trying again on a clean XP installation ... or even better, use Everything instead of WDS :)

Comment: Yeah, I am thinking of giving up...I've tried everything and nothing is pointing me to the right direction.

I get a new laptop in a few weeks, so hopefully that will help

Comment: @Ben Baril - as i said, have a look at Everything and see what it can do for you: http://www.voidtools.com/ or Agent Ransack: http://www.mythicsoft.com/agentransack/

Answer (score 0):

Doing a bit of reading around your topic i have found this article which has been used by people getting similar errors as yourself, regarding WDS 3.1 albeit.
This has seemed to fix the problem in most cases I have seen it mentioned.
[Link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/astebner/solving-setup-errors-by-using-the-subinacl-tool-to-repair-file-and-registry-permissions)

Its these two lines that got me thinking it could be a registry error:
17.0.579: In Function TestVolatileFlag, line 12013, RegOpenKeyEx failed with error 0x2
18.0.579: In Function TestVolatileFlag, line 12045, RegOpenKeyEx failed with error 0x2

Worth a try, anyway. Let us know how it goes.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure that this is your problem, but, I do know that "Windows Desktop Search 4.0" will only install on a 32-bit machine.

You have to install [Windows Desktop Search 3.01 for Windows XP x64 Edition](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11230)  version on 64-bit computers.

Comment: Thank you for the text expansion. I get it. If microsoft ever breaks the link (which is likely), the information is still helpful.